# NestJS : database connection (TypeORM) by request (subdomain)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to build a SAAS product over Nest/TypeORM and I need to configure/change database connection by subdomain.

```
customer1.domain.com => connect to customer1 database
customer2.domain.com => connect to customer2 database
x.domain.com => connect to x database
```

How can I do that ? With interceptors or request-context (or Zone.js) ?

I don't know how to start. Is someone already do that ?

---

WIP : what I am currently doing :

1. add all connections settings into ormconfig file
2. create Middleware on all routes to inject subdomain into `res.locals` (instance name) and create/warn typeorm connection

   ```
   import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, MiddlewareFunction } from '@nestjs/common';
   import { getConnection, createConnection } from "typeorm";

   @Injectable()
   export class DatabaseMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
       resolve(): MiddlewareFunction {
         return async (req, res, next) => {
             const instance = req.headers.host.split('.')[0]
             res.locals.instance = instance

             try {
                 getConnection(instance)
             } catch (error) {
                 await createConnection(instance)
             }

             next();
         };
       }
   }
   ```
3. in Controller : get instance name from @Response and pass it to my Service

   ```
   @Controller('/catalog/categories')
   export class CategoryController {
       constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}

       @Get()
       async getList(@Query() query: SearchCategoryDto, @Response() response): Promise<Category[]> {
         return response.send(
           await this.categoryService.findAll(response.locals.instance, query)
         )
       }
   ```
4. in Service : get TypeORM Manager for given instance and query database through Repository

   ```
   @Injectable()
   export class CategoryService {
     // constructor(
     //   @InjectRepository(Category) private readonly categoryRepository: Repository<Category>
     // ) {}

     async getRepository(instance: string): Promise<Repository<Category>> {
         return (await getManager(instance)).getRepository(Category)
     }

     async findAll(instance: string, dto: SearchCategoryDto): Promise<Category[]> {
       let queryBuilder = (await this.getRepository(instance)).createQueryBuilder('category')

       if (dto.name) {
           queryBuilder.andWhere("category.name like :name", { name: `%${dto.name}%` })
       }

       return await queryBuilder.getMany();
     }
   ```

It seems to work but I not sure about pretty much everything :

- connections poole (how many can I create connections into my ConnectionManager ?)
- pass subdomain into response.locals... bad practice ?
- readability / comprehension / adding lot of additional code...
- side effects : I'm afraid to share connections between several subdomains
- side effects : performance

It's not a pleasure to deals with response.send() + Promise + await(s) + pass subdomain everywhere...

Is there a way to get subdomain directly into my Service ?

Is there a way to get correct subdomain Connection/Repository directly into my Service and Inject it into my Controller ?

Comment: You should configure this using enviroment variables, defined just before you start your node server, like: `DOMAIN=customer1.domain.com node server.js` (if you're on linux). To use in your code use `process.env.DOMAIN`

Comment: It means that I need to run one node by sudbomain (1 app / port by subdomain) ... I would like to run one node for all subdomains and switch db connection per request.

Answer (score 6):

I came up with another solution.

I created a middleware to get the connection for a specific tenant:

```
import { createConnection, getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { Tenancy } from '@src/tenancy/entity/tenancy.entity';

export function tenancyConnection(...modules: Array<{ new(...args: any[]): 
any; }>) {

  return async (req, res, next) => {

    const tenant = req.headers.host.split(process.env.DOMAIN)[0].slice(0, -1);

    // main database connection
    let con = ...

    // get db config that is stored in the main db
    const tenancyRepository = await con.getRepository(Tenancy);
    const db_config = await tenancyRepository.findOne({ subdomain: tenant });

    let connection;
    try {
       connection = await getConnection(db_config.name);
    } catch (e) {
      connection = await createConnection(db_config.config);
    }

    // stores connection to selected modules
    for (let module of modules) {
      Reflect.defineMetadata('__tenancyConnection__', connection, module);
    }

    next();
  };
}
```

I added it to the main.ts:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.use(tenancyConnection(AppModule));
```

To access the connection you can extend any service by:

```
export class TenancyConnection {

  getConnection(): Connection {
    return Reflect.getMetadata('__tenancyConnection__', AppModule);
  }
}
```

It is still a draft, but with this solution you can add, delete and edit the connection for each tenant at runtime.
I hope this helps you further.

Comment: Hello TenancyConnection is a controller or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I got inspired by yoh's solution but I tweaked it a bit according to the new features in NestJS. The result is less code.

1) I created `DatabaseMiddleware`

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getConnection, createConnection, ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

  public static COMPANY_NAME = 'company_name';

  async use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    const databaseName = req.headers[DatabaseMiddleware.COMPANY_NAME];

    const connection: ConnectionOptions = {
      type: "mysql",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3307,
      username: "***",
      password: "***",
      database: databaseName,
      name: databaseName,
      entities: [
        "dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}",
        "src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"
      ],
      synchronize: false
    };

    try {
      getConnection(connection.name);
    } catch (error) {
      await createConnection(connection);
    }

    next();
  }

}
```

2) in main.ts use it for every routes

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.use(new DatabaseMiddleware().use);
  ...
```

3) In service retrieve connection

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository, getManager } from 'typeorm';
import { MyEntity } from './my-entity.entity';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { DatabaseMiddleware } from '../connections';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private repository: Repository<MyEntity>;

  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request) { 
    this.repository = getManager(this.request.headers[DatabaseMiddleware.COMPANY_NAME]).getRepository(MyEntity);
  }

  async findOne(): Promise<MyEntity> {
    return await this.repository
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I am getting error if I applied this solution..[[Nest] 43292   - 2019-10-10 04:19:31   [ExceptionsHandler] Connection "default" was not found. +1260ms
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.]

Comment: @WinterTime: you need to set a 'virtual' connection in your app.module.ts like this:     `@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot( {
      type: "sqlite",
      database: ":memory:",
      entities: entities,
      dropSchema: true,
      entities: entities,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: false,
      name: name
    }),
    CaseModule,
    CompanyInfoModule,
    TeamModule,
  ],
})`

because connection is determined with each request, but TypeORM needs to have a 'default' connection at the beginning.

Comment: Tested this solution yesterday, sounds pretty good however in nest you cannot get req.body in Middleware for some reason so I need to have a look if there is any other possibility.

Comment: @WinterTime can you send the particular information in HTTP header?

Comment: I was being told it can cause race conditions or other errors to call an async method in constructor. you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a custom provider with `REQUEST` scope.

**Tenancy provider**

```js
import { Global, Module, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Connection, createConnection, getConnectionManager } from 'typeorm';

const connectionFactory = {
  provide: 'CONNECTION',
  scope: Scope.REQUEST,
  useFactory: async (req) => {
    const instance = req.headers.host.split('.')[0]
    if (instance) {
      const connectionManager = getConnectionManager();

      if (connectionManager.has(instance)) {
        const connection = connectionManager.get(instance);
        return Promise.resolve(connection.isConnected ? connection : connection.connect());
      }

      return createConnection({
        ...tenantsOrmconfig,
        entities: [...(tenantsOrmconfig as any).entities, ...(ormconfig as any).entities],
        name: instance,
        type: 'postgres',
        schema: instance
      });
    }
  },
  inject: [REQUEST]
};

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [connectionFactory],
  exports: ['CONNECTION']
})
export class TenancyModule { }
```

**Service class**

Then on your services you can get the connection like that:

```js
import { Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { GameEntity } from './game.entity';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('CONNECTION') connection
  ) {
    this.myRepository = connection.getRepository(GameEntity);
  }

  findAll(): Promise<GameEntity[]> {
    return this.myRepository.find();
  }

}
```

You can get more informations in the following multi-tenants article: https://tech.canyonlegal.com/multitenancy-with-nestjs-typeorm-postgres

Comment: The mentioned article has now been moved to this link: https://thomasvds.com/schema-based-multitenancy-with-nest-js-type-orm-and-postgres-sql/, with some refactos brought along the way (based on the original article by @adrien_om, along with the related Github repository

Answer (score 0):

I write an implementation for this issue for [nest-mongodb](https://github.com/erikc5000/nest-mongodb/issues/2), please check it out it might help.

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842819/7377682

```
import {
    Module,
    Inject,
    Global,
    DynamicModule,
    Provider,
    OnModuleDestroy,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModuleRef } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MongoClient, MongoClientOptions } from 'mongodb';
import {
    DEFAULT_MONGO_CLIENT_OPTIONS,
    MONGO_MODULE_OPTIONS,
    DEFAULT_MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME,
    MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME,
} from './mongo.constants';
import {
    MongoModuleAsyncOptions,
    MongoOptionsFactory,
    MongoModuleOptions,
} from './interfaces';
import { getClientToken, getContainerToken, getDbToken } from './mongo.util';
import * as hash from 'object-hash';

@Global()
@Module({})
export class MongoCoreModule implements OnModuleDestroy {
    constructor(
        @Inject(MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME) private readonly containerName: string,
        private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
    ) {}

    static forRoot(
        uri: string,
        dbName: string,
        clientOptions: MongoClientOptions = DEFAULT_MONGO_CLIENT_OPTIONS,
        containerName: string = DEFAULT_MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME,
    ): DynamicModule {

        const containerNameProvider = {
            provide: MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME,
            useValue: containerName,
        };

        const connectionContainerProvider = {
            provide: getContainerToken(containerName),
            useFactory: () => new Map<any, MongoClient>(),
        };

        const clientProvider = {
            provide: getClientToken(containerName),
            useFactory: async (connections: Map<any, MongoClient>) => {
                const key = hash.sha1({
                    uri: uri,
                    clientOptions: clientOptions,
                });
                if (connections.has(key)) {
                    return connections.get(key);
                }
                const client = new MongoClient(uri, clientOptions);
                connections.set(key, client);
                return await client.connect();
            },
            inject: [getContainerToken(containerName)],
        };

        const dbProvider = {
            provide: getDbToken(containerName),
            useFactory: (client: MongoClient) => client.db(dbName),
            inject: [getClientToken(containerName)],
        };

        return {
            module: MongoCoreModule,
            providers: [
                containerNameProvider,
                connectionContainerProvider,
                clientProvider,
                dbProvider,
            ],
            exports: [clientProvider, dbProvider],
        };
    }

    static forRootAsync(options: MongoModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
        const mongoContainerName =
            options.containerName || DEFAULT_MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME;

        const containerNameProvider = {
            provide: MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME,
            useValue: mongoContainerName,
        };

        const connectionContainerProvider = {
            provide: getContainerToken(mongoContainerName),
            useFactory: () => new Map<any, MongoClient>(),
        };

        const clientProvider = {
            provide: getClientToken(mongoContainerName),
            useFactory: async (
                connections: Map<any, MongoClient>,
                mongoModuleOptions: MongoModuleOptions,
            ) => {
                const { uri, clientOptions } = mongoModuleOptions;
                const key = hash.sha1({
                    uri: uri,
                    clientOptions: clientOptions,
                });
                if (connections.has(key)) {
                    return connections.get(key);
                }
                const client = new MongoClient(
                    uri,
                    clientOptions || DEFAULT_MONGO_CLIENT_OPTIONS,
                );
                connections.set(key, client);
                return await client.connect();
            },
            inject: [getContainerToken(mongoContainerName), MONGO_MODULE_OPTIONS],
        };

        const dbProvider = {
            provide: getDbToken(mongoContainerName),
            useFactory: (
                mongoModuleOptions: MongoModuleOptions,
                client: MongoClient,
            ) => client.db(mongoModuleOptions.dbName),
            inject: [MONGO_MODULE_OPTIONS, getClientToken(mongoContainerName)],
        };

        const asyncProviders = this.createAsyncProviders(options);

        return {
            module: MongoCoreModule,
            imports: options.imports,
            providers: [
                ...asyncProviders,
                clientProvider,
                dbProvider,
                containerNameProvider,
                connectionContainerProvider,
            ],
            exports: [clientProvider, dbProvider],
        };
    }

    async onModuleDestroy() {
        const clientsMap: Map<any, MongoClient> = this.moduleRef.get<
            Map<any, MongoClient>
        >(getContainerToken(this.containerName));

        if (clientsMap) {
            await Promise.all(
                [...clientsMap.values()].map(connection => connection.close()),
            );
        }
    }

    private static createAsyncProviders(
        options: MongoModuleAsyncOptions,
    ): Provider[] {
        if (options.useExisting || options.useFactory) {
            return [this.createAsyncOptionsProvider(options)];
        } else if (options.useClass) {
            return [
                this.createAsyncOptionsProvider(options),
                {
                    provide: options.useClass,
                    useClass: options.useClass,
                },
            ];
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }

    private static createAsyncOptionsProvider(
        options: MongoModuleAsyncOptions,
    ): Provider {
        if (options.useFactory) {
            return {
                provide: MONGO_MODULE_OPTIONS,
                useFactory: options.useFactory,
                inject: options.inject || [],
            };
        } else if (options.useExisting) {
            return {
                provide: MONGO_MODULE_OPTIONS,
                useFactory: async (optionsFactory: MongoOptionsFactory) =>
                    await optionsFactory.createMongoOptions(),
                inject: [options.useExisting],
            };
        } else if (options.useClass) {
            return {
                provide: MONGO_MODULE_OPTIONS,
                useFactory: async (optionsFactory: MongoOptionsFactory) =>
                    await optionsFactory.createMongoOptions(),
                inject: [options.useClass],
            };
        } else {
            throw new Error('Invalid MongoModule options');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23996153)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Noted

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be using a dynamic module just like you did with request scope to get `ORM` connection and make it connections specific.
a really simple sample could be like this:

```js
const tenancyFactory: Provider = {
    provide: NEST_MYSQL2_TENANCY,
    scope: 'REQUEST',
    useFactory: async (mysql: Mysql, options: MysqlTenancyOption, req: Request): Promise<any> => {
        console.log("TENANCY FACTORY");

        const executer = function (mysqlPool: Mysql): MysqlExecuter {
            return {
                db: function (dbName: string): MysqlRunner {
                    return {
                        run: async function (sqlString: string) {
                            const q = `\nUSE ${dbName};\n` +
                                sqlString.replace("; ", ";\n");
                            if (options.debug) {
                                tLogger.verbose(q);
                            }
                            const [[_, ...queryResult], __] = await mysqlPool.query(q)
                            return queryResult as any;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return executer(mysql);
    },
    inject: [NEST_MYSQL2_CONNECTION, NEST_MYSQL2_TENANCY_OPTION],
};

@Global()
@Module({
    providers: [tenancyFactory],
    exports: [tenancyFactory],
})
export class MultiTenancyModule {
    constructor(

    ) { }
    public static register(options: MysqlTenancyOption): DynamicModule {
        return {
            module: MultiTenancyModule,
            providers: [{
                provide: NEST_MYSQL2_TENANCY_OPTION,
                useValue: options
            }]
        };
    }
}
```

in this sample I have user mysql2-nestjs module but you can use your own `ORM` to create `tenancyFactory`

you find this sample in a working solution in below ling
https://github.com/golkhandani/multi-tenancy/blob/main/test/src/tenancy.module.ts