# How to dynamically connect to a database in nestjs?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have multiple databases that I want to connect. but just one of them have static name. for example the name of that database is `stores`, and in that I have a table that indicates the name of the other databases. now I want to change the connection provider after the first route being called. how can I do that?

I tried to use the Dynamic modules, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Create your own Database module, and pass a database name to provider, or uri that you want to connect with, store somewhere these information with relations to the connection, like string -> connection, fe: Map with DB URI or DB Name with key as connection handler. Then you should be able to achieve your goal.

Comment: @cojack, thanks. but can you give an example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class MongooseConfigService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
    constructor(
        @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,) {
    }

    createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {
        return {
            uri: request.params.uri, // Change this to whatever you want
        };
    }
}
```

You can read more about [Injection Scopes](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes)

And can see the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571382/how-to-change-a-database-connection-dynamically-with-request-scope-providers-in) here