# Dynamic MonoDB connection for child modules - NestJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm trying to implement Multi-tenancy application which will have the collection of org details, and the org data will be stored in different databases.
Like,
[image]

When someone do the API call, I'll be adding `x-org-id` header which will send the org ID which is database name.

I have 2 modules

1. Org Details
2. Users

I've added database connection at the `app.module.ts` as below

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DB),
    OrgModule,
    UserModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
```

`process.env.DB` will have the master database connection something like `mongodb://localhost/my_master_db`. When the org is created, I'll be saving the data in `my_master_db` database in `org_details` collection. From here, I'll get the `_id` which is generated by `MongoDB` and use that as database name for saving the users.

all org related APIs will be in `http://localost:3000/org` endpoint. here I want to connect to `my_master_db`.

All the users related API endpoints will be in `http://localost:3000/user`, and here I want to change the database connection to `mongodb://localhost2/{org_id}` from the API request header `x-org-id`.

I've tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571382/how-to-change-a-database-connection-dynamically-with-request-scope-providers-in) solution, By creating a service which uses `Scope.REQUEST` Injector, it looks like its not working. When I use it on `app.module.ts` It works, but when I import it on `user.module.ts`, it wont work.

My `mongoose.service.ts` file is as below

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseOptionsFactory, MongooseModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class MongooseConfigService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
    constructor(
        @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {
            console.log("Injected", "Injected");
    }

    createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {
        return {
             uri: this.request.headers['x-org-id'],
        };
    }
}
```

My `db.module.ts` file is as below

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { MongooseConfigService } from './mognoose.service';

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            useClass: MongooseConfigService,
        }),
    ]
})
export class DbModule {}
```

And I'm importing the `DbModule` to my `UserModule` as below

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: "users", schema: UserModel}]),
    HrmDbModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserProvider]
})
```

How do I fix the issue? What's the best way to connect to Different Databases on the `router` level?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check https://github.com/needle-innovision/nestjs-tenancy

Ready solution with tenant id(from header)/subdomain implementation.

No Graphql support (20 Dec 22).