# How to open a connection to a mongo database based on a rabbitmq message in nestjs using @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I scatered the web for this answer or something similar but with no avail. I did found something that may help explain what am I looking for.

I want to get multiple Mongo connection in a Nestjs project based on a payload received from a RabbitMQ broker. Is there a way to do this in a similar way like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571382/how-to-change-a-database-connection-dynamically-with-request-scope-providers-in) post with the interception of the request in the declaration of the MongooseModule?

```
@Module( {
  imports: [ RabbitMQModule.forRootAsync( RabbitMQModule, {
    imports: [ ConfigModule ],
    useClass: AmqpConfig,
    inject: [ ConfigService ],
  } ) ],
  controllers: [ MessagingController ],
  providers: [ MessagingService, ConfigService ],
  exports: [ MessagingService, RabbitMQModule ]
} )
export class MessagingModule { }
```

The AmqpConfig class

```
@Injectable()
export class RabbitConfig {
    constructor (
        private readonly config: ConfigService,
    ) { }

    createModuleConfig (): RabbitMQConfig | Promise<RabbitMQConfig> {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            uri: this.uri,
            exchanges: this.exchanges,
            connectionInitOptions: this.connectionInitOptions,
            enableControllerDiscovery: true,
        };
    }

    get uri (): string {
        const { host, port } = this.config.get( 'amqp' );
        return `${ host }:${ port || 5672 }`;
    }

    get name (): string {
        return this.config.get( 'amqp' ).name;
    }

    get exchanges (): Array<RabbitMQExchangeConfig> {
        return Object.values( this.config.get( 'amqp' ).exchanges ) as Array<RabbitMQExchangeConfig>;
    }

    get connectionInitOptions () {
        return this.config.get( 'amqp' ).connectionInitOptions;
    }
};
```

How exactly should I configure the MongooseModule?

```
@Module( {
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot( {
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [ envConfig ]
    } ),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync( {
      useClass: MongoConfig,
      inject: [ ConfigService ]
    } )
  ],
  controllers: [ AppController ],
  providers: [ AppService ],
} )
export class AppModule { }
```

MongoConfig class:

```
export class MongoConfig implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
    constructor ( private readonly config: ConfigService ) { }
    createMongooseOptions (): MongooseModuleOptions | Promise<MongooseModuleOptions> {
        return {
            uri: this.uri
        };
    }

    get uri () {
        return this.config.get( 'mongo' ).uri;
    }
}
```