# Build Nest.js app with multitenancy(using postgres schema's per tenant and sequelise ORM) and dynamically switch schema?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, database-schema, nestjs

Our team decided to go with Nest.js for SaaS based application and are new to node.js environment. For the DB store we used postgres which supports multiple schemas per tenant and sequelise is our ORM. Right now we are facing a issue of how to dynamically switch the schema. After doing a lot of research, we could not find a solid way to go about. Below are few things which we came across,

- We came across dynamic schema switching w.r.t typeOrm of nest.js, where they switch schema dynamically in the middleware and re-instantiate the DB connection instance, use this by injecting in the services or where ever necessary.

  ref:

  1) [NestJS : database connection (TypeORM) by request (subdomain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385738/nestjs-database-connection-typeorm-by-request-subdomain)

  2) [NestJS Request Scoped Multitenancy for Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583231/nestjs-request-scoped-multitenancy-for-multiple-databases/56943281#56943281)
- The other method was to use "scope: Scope.REQUEST", as per the documentation, which also warns about performance issue's.

Now my question is since node.js is a single threaded environment, I want 
to know which of the below mentioned way's is a best use case for 
sequelise.

- create a middle ware and set the schema name dynamically to the request headers.

> Option 1:

From the documentation of sequelise, there is a an option to set the
search path using 'options.searchPath' for each of the orm method's(find,
 findAll ...). Since node.js is single threaded, passing the schema name in
 request header and using it in the queries like this,does it cause any 
issue's to be aware of. In Ruby On Rails we have separate threads using
"thread.current" to handle this, can any one explain this approach?

- https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync

> Option 2:

Since we have a code based already, is there a way like the typeOrm version
of getting the sequelise db connection dynamically as mentioned above so 
that we don't change anywhere else in the existing code, if so how to do
that?

Thanks

Comment: found a solution?